# angular route to children

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

Angular basic routing question:
This is my Routes structure in my app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{  path: 'ManagerDataContainer', component:ManagerDataContainerComponent,
  children:
  [
     { path: 'SysUsersForm', component: UsersFormComponent }
  ]
 ....
```

In the **ManagerDataContainer** component, I have some kind of data structure, and I would like to route from an anchor to the SysUsersForm, by doing so:

```
<a [routerLink]= "getRouterByScreenID(screen.ScreenID)"...
```

which should be evaluated to:

```
<a routerLink= "SysUsersForm">AAAAAAA</a>
```

or even

```
<a routerLink= "/SysUsersForm" routerLinkActive="active">AAA</a>
```

This is the template of the ManagerDataContainer:

```
   <div>
     <div *ngFor="let XXX of YYYYYYY">
         <!-- <a [routerLink]= "getRouterByScreenID(screen.ScreenID)" 
                       routerLinkActive="active">AAAAA</a>   -->
        <!-- <a [routerLink]= "SysUsersForm" routerLinkActive="active"> 
                              AAAAAA</a>   -->
       <a routerLink= "SysUsersForm" routerLinkActive="active">AAAA</a>  
    </div>
    <div class="tableViewContainer">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I keep getting: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'SysUsersForm'"

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: could you provide an example on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write routerLink like as below,

routerLink= "/ManagerDataContainer/SysUsersForm"

this is me be help you

Comment: I'm in the ManagerDataContainer component - where the <router-outlet></router-outlet> exists - I want the <router-outlet></router-outlet> to be populated with the SysUsersForm

Comment: If you can  use children in route that's why need to give full path in routerlink

Answer (score 0):

The ManagerDataContainer wasn't needed to be in the router configuration - there isn't any routing there - I just needed to declare the configuration of SysUsersForm as follow:

```
{  path: 'SysUsersForm', component:UsersFormComponent}
```